# Animating UILabel with CoreAnimation / QuartzCore in iOS App

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, core-animation, quartz-core

I actually stuck on a problem with animating a UILabel in my iOS Application.
After 2 days of searching the web for code snippets, still no result.

Every sample I found was about how to animate UIImage, adding it as a subview to UIView by layer. Is there any good example about animating a UILabel?
I found a nice solution for a blinking animation by setting the alpha property, like this:

My function:

```
- (void)blinkAnimation:(NSString *)animationID finished:(BOOL)finished target:(UIView *)target
{
    NSString *selectedSpeed = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"EffectSpeed"];
    float speedFloat = (1.00 - [selectedSpeed floatValue]);

    [UIView beginAnimations:animationID context:target];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:speedFloat];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(blinkAnimation:finished:target:)];

    if([target alpha] == 1.0f)
        [target setAlpha:0.0f];
    else
        [target setAlpha:1.0f];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Call my function on the UILabel:

```
[self blinkAnimation:@"blinkAnimation" finished:YES target:labelView];
```

But how about a Pulse, or scaling animation?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Unfortunately font size is not an animatable property of NSView.  In order to scale a UILabel, you'll need to use more advanced [Core Animation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Introduction/Introduction.html) techniques, using [CAKeyframeAnimation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CAKeyframeAnimation_class/Introduction/Introduction.html):

1. Import the QuartzCore.framework into your project, and `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>` in your code.
2. Create a new [CAKeyframeAnimation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CAKeyframeAnimation_class/Introduction/Introduction.html) object that you can add your key frames to.
3. Create a [CATransform3D](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Articles/Layers.html) value defining the scaling operation (don't get confused by the 3D part--you use this object to do *any* transformations on a layer).
4. Make the transformation one of the keyframes in the animation by adding it to the [CAKeyframeAnimation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CAKeyframeAnimation_class/Introduction/Introduction.html) object using its `setValues` method.
5. Set a duration for the animation by calling its `setDuration` method
6. Finally, add the animation to the label's layer using `[[yourLabelObject layer] addAnimation:yourCAKeyframeAnimationObject forKey:@"anyArbitraryString"`]

The final code could look something like this:

```
// Create the keyframe animation object
CAKeyframeAnimation *scaleAnimation = 
   [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform"];

// Set the animation's delegate to self so that we can add callbacks if we want
scaleAnimation.delegate = self;

// Create the transform; we'll scale x and y by 1.5, leaving z alone 
// since this is a 2D animation.
CATransform3D transform = CATransform3DMakeScale(1.5, 1.5, 1); // Scale in x and y

// Add the keyframes.  Note we have to start and end with CATransformIdentity, 
// so that the label starts from and returns to its non-transformed state.
[scaleAnimation setValues:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                  [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DIdentity],
                  [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:transform],
                  [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DIdentity],
                  nil]];

// set the duration of the animation
[scaleAnimation setDuration: .5];

// animate your label layer = rock and roll!
[[self.label layer] addAnimation:scaleAnimation forKey:@"scaleText"];
```

I'll leave the repeating "pulse" animation as an exercise for you: hint, it involves the `animationDidStop` method!

One other note--the full list of CALayer animatable properties (of which "transform" is one) can be found [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Articles/AnimProps.html).  Happy tweening!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed answer. I already solved the problem, using CABasicAnimation with a timer. I'm sure your code will also work fine, so you get the accept. ;)